# Button doesn't work on real phone, but works on android studio emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, apk

Using Build->Build APK, I tried to install my app into my phone. Everything works fine including the button, on the emulator.

However, when I try using it on my phone, pressing the button crashes my phone. Floating action button works, but not

I tried commenting out the startActivity functions that are linked to the button, but it still crashes.
Any possible reasons why?

Sorry if it is a bit vague, but I am not sure what the root of the problem is.

I tried setting backToMainScreen method to nothing, but the app still crashes,  so I don't think it is a problem with the java code.

One of the pages that caused problem

```
public class AddExercise extends AppCompatActivity {

private ArrayList<Exercise> exList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.add_exercise);
    exList =  MainActivity.loadData();
}

void backToMainScreen(View target){
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),    MainActivity.class);
    MainActivity.saveData(exList);

    startActivity(myIntent);
    finish();
}

void addExercise(View target){

    EditText etNewEntry = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.newEntry);
    String newEntry = etNewEntry.getText().toString();
    if (!newEntry.isEmpty()) {
        Exercise newExercise = new Exercise(newEntry);
        exList.add(newExercise);
    }

    backToMainScreen(target);

}


}
```

Here is the XML code for that page

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/popupWindow">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/exInput"
    android:layout_above="@+id/newEntry"
    android:gravity="center"/>

<EditText
    android:layout_width="200sp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/newEntry"

    android:layout_above="@+id/buttons"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/buttons"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/buttons"
   android:inputType="textAutoComplete"/>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/buttons"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="100sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/ok"
        android:text="@string/ok"
        android:onClick="addExercise"
        />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="100sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/cancel"
        android:text="@string/cancel"
        android:onClick="backToMainScreen"
        />

</LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/) ! Please read  [How to Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and by posting your code provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for `android:onClick` to work your target function should be `public`.

```
public void backToMainScreen(View target){}

public void addExercise(View target){}
```

Comment: thanks a lot. Is there any reason why it works on emulator though? Is it some sort of well known bug/design of android studio that allow non-public methods to work for onClick?

Comment: @Hugi I am not sure why it worked on the emulator. It is well documented that function should be public (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html) - If it fixed your problem then you can accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

In order for this to work, the method must be public and accept a View as its only parameter. 
Please make your methods public in your code for the button click.

Read the documentation
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html